# Django's "check" cannot import settings

Tags: python, django, static-analysis

Since the project is evolving I would like to start executing the system check framework of Django on dev environment. The technology stack is Ubuntu, PostgreSQL, Django1.9 + UWSGI. But...

```
django-admin check
```

outputs the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named my_project.settings
```

The `wsgi.py` file contains:

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('~/virtenv/my_site')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_site.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The env variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` echoes `my_site.settings`

It is important to mention that the `settings.py` file is in `virtenv/my_site/my_site/` . Please also note that the entire web application is running fine, I am also using the features of `manage.py`. Its just the `django-admin check` that is getting on my nerves.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't call the wsgi file, Make sure you add the project path to the sys path for the environment you're using

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Updating the `PYTHONPATH` with `/home/username/virtenv/my_site` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you seem to append to the sys path in the wsgi but the admin `check` won't be using that.

Make sure you add the project path to the sys path for the environment you're using